# SSRS Layout is not same as Report builder

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder

Im creating A report in SSRS Report builder bt problem is when i preview the reportin report builder everything working fine bt when i save on server and open in Firefox, Edge and chorme totally layour mess

is there nay one help me out to fix this problem [Report Builder lay put](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtK2t.png)

[Web layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQPxO.png)

Comment: You'll need to show your design layout too before anyone will be able to offer much help. Please edit your question and include the design layout.

Comment: Did my suggestions help at all?

Answer (score 0):

There are two main things you can do to help keep the alignment as you expect it to be.

1. Wrap sets of objects in a rectangle. Rectangles go a long way in preserving report layouts when you run them.
2. Manually set the position of each object. Tables and other report objects are not allowed to overlap. So if they are overlapping in any way, one will be moved out of the way. By setting the exact positions, you avoid rounding errors and accidental overlaps.

If you have done these and are still having issues, set the textboxes `CanGrow` property to false. This will help prevent them from bumping into other objects near them.